# Mixing between “lookup” column type and “People or Group” column type

Tags: 2013, content-type, lookup-column, column, people-picker

I want to create a site column that contain a list of “Project Managers”, where some project managers are already defined inside Active directory and are defined inside a SharePoint security group , while other project managers are external users that are not defined inside our active directory. so what I need is a column type that is  a mixture between:-

- Users from a security group . Similar to a column with “People or Group” type that is associated with a security group.
- External users defined inside a list. Similar to a “lookup” column associated with a custom list.

So is there a way to have a single site column that contains both info?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not column like this.

The best you could do would be to store the data in a separate list with the title column being the display name of the user and a second column for their email address and any other columns for additional data you want. Then when you create a lookup column to this list, you can include any other fields that might be necessary by ticking the check box beside them in the lookup column configuration.

Comment: so you mean i need to manully add internal and external users to the separate list ? second question;  i did not understand very well what do you mean by " you can include any other fields that might be necessary by ticking the check box beside them in the lookup column configuration." ??

Comment: That is how I would handle it yes, it's a bit hacky but really there is no other alternative of having a person group field with users not in your domain. What I meant was, when you create a lookup column against this list, you can pull in additional fields as you want. They show up as checkboxes in the lookup column creation, add anything that might be necessary.